# Sticky navigation bar won't follow page scrolling in Internet Explorer and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've coded a website in Safari that works exactly as I want it. But, it seems as the horisontal sticky navbar won't follow page scrolling in Internet Explorer, Chrome and Firefox.

I've tried to apply overflow: auto, but it doesn't help and I have a hard time to solve this. Anyone know how to do it?

```
  <div id="navbar">
<div id="navbar-links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME |</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#features">FEATURES |</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#xxx">XXX |</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#xxx">XXX |</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#xxx">XXX |</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#demo">DEMO |</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#xxx">XXX |</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#xxx">XXX |</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#contact">CONTACT |</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="navbar-logo">
  <a href="index.html"><h1>NAME<img src="images/logo.png" height="30px" width="30px"></h1></a>
</div>
```

```
#navbar h1{
    font-family: "Gill Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 2%;
}
#navbar-logo a{
    font-family: "Gill Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 2%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
}
#navbar{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14px 10px 4px 10px;
    position: -webkit-sticky;  
    top: 0;  
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
#logo{
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#navbar-links{
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-right: 2%;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: right;
}

#navbar-links ul{
    width: 100%;

    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
}
    #navbar-links li{
        display: inline;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #navbar-links li a:link{
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #navbar-links li a:visited {
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #navbar-links li a:hover{
        color: #c3c3c3;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #navbar-links li a:active{
        color: #c3c3c3;
        text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#navbar { position: fixed; }
```

Webkit is the rendering engine for Apple Safari browsers and thus `position: -webkit-sticky` will not work in other browsers. Read more about CSS `position` property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Above post might answer the question, but little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand how it works.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome :)

To asker: webkit is the rendering engine for Apple Safari browsers and thus position: -webkit-sticky will not work in other browsers. Read more about CSS position property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)